# Can I use Couchdb as a webserver and the only backend?

Tags: webserver, couchdb, backend

I'm studying Couchdb right now. It looks like I could use Couchdb as a backend and web server without needing anything else. Am I correct? Do people use Couchdb as a only backend? Are there any disadvantages doing so?

Comment: `Futon` and now `Fauxton` are the proof that it's possible to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core team seems to have pulled back from this in recent versions, but a few years ago there was a lot more of a push to run standalone apps straight out of the CouchDB, these standalone apps are called "Couch Apps".

I don't know it was ever really more than a proof-of-concept (ie. I don't know that any significant web app is actually running on this platform), but if you're interested, apparently the tools do all still work, and there's still the http://couchapp.org/ site with a lot of good information.

#### Update

I want to add that if the problem you're trying to solve is the problem of javascript origin security, then you should know that [recent CouchDB supports CORS](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/configuring.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing)

Comment: I updated my answer, just in case this is what you (or someone else who finds this question) is trying to do.